# undefined reference to Class::Method on 3rd party library

Tags: c++, linux, qt4

I have one 3rd party c++ library for both Linux and Windows, this I'm importing into QT project and trying to call some method. On WinXP (MinGW 3.4.5) it compiles, but on Linux 64bit (gcc 4.8.2) I'm getting: Undefined reference to Class::Method for many methods called within the library. Eg. I'm not even calling them.

Oder of ld parameters is handled by qmake, and test with other libraries are fine.

Is there some way how-to check if library should work? Or could it be some incompatibility between g++ 3.5 and 4.8?

```
$file libbase.so.1.0.0
libpbase.so.1.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=fccb75e93971bd702949224d961b8e78b33ac875, not stripped
```

$nm libbase.so.1.0.0
is also showing that all missing methods are there.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you linking in the correct order? Because order matters, for example always put libraries last on the command line if you build or link manually.

Comment: I think you might have missed the header file for `libbase.so`. Are you sure you have included the header file?

Answer (score 0):

The library was linked to other library and there were some methods missing. I've read nm manual and all those reported methods were: "U" The symbol is undefined. Then I checked rest of the libraries and those methods are simply not delivered.